# Return first five values from spotify web service

Tags: jquery, spotify

I am using the spotify web api and jquery ui auto-complete. I am trying to only return the first five item in the response rather the the whole list.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
    $("#spotify_song_search").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.get("http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/artist.json", {
              //currently selected in input
                q: request.term
            }, function(data) {
                response($.map(data.artists, function(item) {
                    return {label: item.name, artist: item};
                }));
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `slice()` to cut the array you pass to jquery map function, so, change your following line:

```
 response($.map(data.artists, function(item) {
```

for this one:

```
 response($.map(data.artists.slice(0,5), function(item) {
```